# How to do dynamic image source in react native (expo)?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a simple function to display a playing card in my react native (expo) project.  It works when testing locally but not when building for a device (APK, etc).  From my understanding it is because the string in `require` can not be dynamic.  If that is the case, what is the best way to handle this issue?
Do I have to do a require for all 52 cards and then pick the appropriate variable for the source of that card? or is there a better way?

```
  export default function Card( { cardID, index, onCardClick }) {

  const rankIndex = cardID % 13;
  const rank = RANKS[rankIndex];
  const suitIndex = cardID / 13 | 0;
  const suit = SUIT[suitIndex];

  let cardImage = require('../../assets/game/cards/'+rank+suit+'.png');

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[index && index != 0 && styles.cardMargin]} onPress={() => onCardClick(cardID)}>
        <Image style={styles.card} source={cardImage} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do something like this:

```
const cardImages = {
  AceSpades: require('../../assets/game/cards/acespaces.png'),
  AceClubs: require('../../assets/game/cards/aceclubs.png'),
  // etc..
};
```

you can generate this array from your filesystem by writing a little node script or create it manually.

metro bundler requires that imports are static.

Comment: Okay, so a variable for each card image does need to be generated.  I was hoping there was a more elegant solution but if that is the way then that is the way.

I will try that and thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should make a function that return all the images as an array and then select the index that of specific image that you want.

Comment: Thanks, this should work too.  I just went with the first solution of putting them all in an array variable in the same file.  Thank you though